# What is the english translation of dialogs spoken over this song?

Tags: lyrics, instrumental

The song "Exploring Yourself With A Knife" is a track form the Russian post-rock band April Rain's album "Waiting For Sunrise". some Russian dialog is spoken between a man and a woman starting at 4:37. could someone provide a transcription or translation ?

The song could be found here on Last.fm:
[Exploring Yourself With A Knife](http://www.last.fm/music/April+Rain/_/Exploring+Yourself+With+A+Knife)

Comment: Maybe worth asking this in the [russian.se] site instead ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs in a Russian language site, and the "belongs in another site in the SE network" option doesn't offer that

Comment: Didn't know there actualy is a russian lanuage site. I will ask it there. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, these kind of questions are in a bit of a cross-over zone. Figuring out words/lyrics is what music fans do, but then again, the language aspect fits with a language forum too, cos everyone likes music.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a translation from Russian.

Answer (score 3):

Female Voice: 4:38  It didn't start today (It's been happening for a while)
Male Voice: 4:40  What?
F: 4:40  I'm losing sensitivity to hot and cold
M: 4:42  Why are you silent?
F: 4:43  I just feel something different..
F: 4:46  Inside
F: 4:47  I don't know how to describe it
F: 4:49  So I..
F: 4:52  Was silent
F: 4:57  Happy now?
M: 5:12  You will blossom
M: 5:19  And I will live
M: 5:29  What are you doing here?
F: 5:31  Walk with me
M: 5:33  I'm working
F: 5:34  So much snow. We always...
M: 5:35  I can't! I have to work
F: 5:38  Come on, Tommy!
M: 5:39  Stop it!
F: 5:47  There's no final chapter in this book
F: 5:53  Will you help me?
M: 5:56  How?
F: 5:58  Finish it
F: 6:03  Finish
M: 6:04  I don't know how it ends
F: 6:06  You know
F: 6:09  You will know
M: 6:11  You should be with me
F: 6:12  I am with you!
F: 6:13  Look!
F: 6:16  I will always be with you
F: 6:20  I promise...

Comment: And it is believed to be taken from russian dubbing of 'The Fountain' by Darren Aronofsky